# checking if the enum exists

Tags: java, enums

I have:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum EnumTest {

    ENUM_TEST1(1),
    ENUM_TEST2(2),
    ENUM_TEST3(3),
    ENUM_TEST4(4),
    ENUM_TEST5(5),
    ENUM_TEST6(6),
    ENUM_TEST7(7),
    ENUM_TEST8(8),
    ENUM_TEST9(9),
    ENUM_TEST10(10);

    private int value;

}
```

I would like to check if a parameter is inside the enum, I can do this:

```
EnumUtils.isValidEnum(EnumTest.class,"ENUM_TEST6");
```

but what would be the correct way to compare only some enum for example, I have this:

```
Arrays.asList(ENUM_TEST6,ENUM_TEST7).contains(newParam.getEnumTest());
```

but asList uses a (new) so it would be correct to do something like this to improve performance a little or what is the best practice you can think of?

```
ENUM_TEST6.equals(newParam.getEnumTest()) || ENUM_TEST7.equals(newParam.getEnumTest());
```

Comment: It wouldn't be a huge performance gain unless you're doing that same operation multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Arrays.asList(ENUM_TEST6,ENUM_TEST7)`, instead use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```java
EnumSet.of(ENUM_TEST6, ENUM_TEST7)
```

If this is something re-usable, add it to the `enum`:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum EnumTest {

    ENUM_TEST1(1),
    ENUM_TEST2(2),
    ENUM_TEST3(3),
    ENUM_TEST4(4),
    ENUM_TEST5(5),
    ENUM_TEST6(6),
    ENUM_TEST7(7),
    ENUM_TEST8(8),
    ENUM_TEST9(9),
    ENUM_TEST10(10);

    private int value;

    private static final EnumSet<EnumTest> TEST_6_7 = EnumSet.of(ENUM_TEST6, ENUM_TEST7);

    public static boolean is6or7(EnumTest value) {
        return TEST_6_7.contains(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the collection of valid enums is very large, you will want to go with the `asList` implementation, but create and store that list in an appropriate scope for reuse.  If the collection of valid enums is small (2-5, say), use of a list (or other collection) is doing a lot of unnecessary work.

But, you would need to adjust the code, if `getEnumTest` answers a string, neither `contains` not `equals` will work.  The collection would be of the names of the enums: `ENUM_TEST6.name()`.

Also, if the collection of valid enums is very large, a `HashSet` would be better, as `List.contains` in basic implementations (say, `ArrayList`) will be slow for large collections.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it this way.  That's what `EnumSets` are for.  They also include

- EnumSet.complementOf
- EnumSet.allOf
- EnumSet.noneOf

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(EnumSet.of(EnumTest.ENUM_TEST1, EnumTest.ENUM_TEST2));

    }   
    public static void method(EnumSet<EnumTest> eset) {
        if (eset.containsAll(EnumSet.of(EnumTest.ENUM_TEST1,EnumTest.ENUM_TEST2))) {
            // do something.
        }
    }
```